# DISK_PERFORMANCE struct's ReadTime and WriteTime members

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, performancecounter

I'm trying to disect the [DISK_PERFORMANCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct but can't seem to find any decent documentation. Does anyone know what the ReadTime and WriteTime members mean?

The MSDN claims, "The time it takes to complete a read/write", but the read/write of what? Also what is it measured in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I didn't know, but I do now.

I wasn't familiar with DISK_PERFORMANCE but I am familiar with the HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA performance data.

The [Avg. Disk sec/Read](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784596%28WS.10%29.aspx) counter reports the average time per read (and there's another counter for writes).  This counter has the [PERF_AVERAGE_TIMER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783087%28WS.10%29.aspx) type.  The data that you actually get is the total time spent reading and the total number of operations.  You acquire two samples and subtract the values to get the total time spent reading during the sample interval and the total number of operations during the sample interval.  You then divide these two values to get the avarage time per read.

The clock frequency is also returned along with the performance data so you can convert the time units to seconds.

Assuming that DISK_PERFORMANCE works similarly then ReadTime and WriteTime will be the total time spent on all reads and writes.  Unfortunately, it's not obvious what clock frequency it's using, but it's most likely using the value from [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I'd try that and see if the results (for average read and write time) compare to the values you see in perfmon.

The header file (winioctl.h) doesn't contain much useful information, but it does say that the IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE request is forwarded to either the DISKPERF filter driver or the SIMBAD filter driver (which simulates disk faults).  Which means you should get consistent results across different device types.

**Update**

So I did the research.  Some sample data:

```
3579000, 42, 801881, 42, 4.46325577
3749000, 79, 839970, 79, 4.46325464
4076000, 66, 913235, 66, 4.463254255
3614000, 77, 809723, 77, 4.463254718
1465000, 28, 328236, 28, 4.46325205
```

Each line has the deltas of the ReadTime and ReadCount members from DISK_PERFORMANCE (sampled once per second) followed by the corresponding values from HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA, followed by the first ReadTime divided by the second.

The HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA values are in QueryPerformanceFrequency units, 2240517Hz on my PC. 10,000,000 / 2240517 = 4.4633 so the DISK_PERFORMANCE metrics seem to be in 100ns (=10MHz) units.

To reiterate, DISK_PERFORMANCE::ReadTime is the total time spend on reads in 100ns units.

Comment: @ahmd0: I don't if you saw my original answer, but I've updated it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for delay. Been busy. So from what you're saying I can determine the read/write speed of a drive, right?

Comment: For instance, to find a drive's current read speed I can get DISK_PERFORMANCE struct 2 times within some time interval (say, 500ms), I can then do: ReadSpeedInBytesPerSecond = (BytesRead - LastBytesRead) * (10000000.0 / (ReadTime - LastReadTime)); Can you confirm this?

Comment: @ahmd0 Yes, that should do it.  To double-check, you can run perfmon and monitor the "Disk Read Bytes/sec" counter to see if the results are similar.

Comment: And sorry for my delay.  I think we must be in wholly incompatible time zones.

Comment: sorry, again. I closed this page and couldn't find it. The thing is that I'm trying to compare the results of my calculations above with the ones returned by Resource Monitor and they vary a lot. I mean, I get 30 Kbytes/sec and Windows tools reports 70 MB/Sec for the same drive (c:). Can it even be possible?

Comment: @ahmd0: I implemented your formula and I'm getting comparable results from both perfmon and Resource Monitor (roughly 50MB/sec for everything).  The code is: `double bytespersec = (nextPerf.BytesRead.QuadPart - diskPerf.BytesRead.QuadPart) * (10000000.0 / (nextPerf.ReadTime.QuadPart - diskPerf.ReadTime.QuadPart))`

Comment: Can I ask you one follow-up? Is it normal for me to get a higher write speed than read speed on an internal HDD? (I tried it on severals PCs with the same result.)

Comment: @ahmd0: I don't know.  Writes might be faster than reads because writes can go into the disk's cache (and get committed later), but reads have to come from the disk (you mostly won't get repeated reads because of Windows' cache).  It's late now, but I might try it on my PC tomorrow.

Comment: @ahmd0: I tried it anyway.  While copying a huge file I found that reads were consistently a bit faster than writes (about 15%).  Though with a huge file copy I wouldn't expect the disk cache to have much of an effect anyway (because it would quickly fill).

Comment: I did more tests. I thought to calculate an average read/write times like so: (using your formula above) if(bytespersec > 0.0){fAvgSpeed = (fAvgSpeed + bytespersec) / 2.0;} where fAvgSpeed is a static member. So I let it run for a day and here's what I get on my drive c: Average Read: 5.31 MBytes/sec, 
Average Write: 20.36 MBytes/sec. Am I doing something wrong? Can you share your code that you try it with?

Comment: In order to calculate the average for an entire day you just need to take a snapshot at either end of the day and do the calculation.  I don't have time to try this now, but as I said, writes may well be faster than reads because of caching.

Comment: @ahmd0: So I ran it for an hour with moderate usage (rather than copying a huge file) and I got 2MB/s for reads and 17MB/s for writes.  I guess write caching explains this as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

In general, like all DeviceIOControl's, it means whatever the underlying driver means. As you can deduce from the `StorageManagerName` member, there are multiple drivers that use this struct.